# Magento 2.4.5 - Good to go?

Tags: bug, magento2.4.5, version-upgrade

Want to use the Magento 2.4.5 for the site, Is there any problem to do this.

Can I go with the 2.4.5 version or I should select lower version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento **2.4.5-P1** is now good:

Modules, 3rd-party modules compatible with PHP 8.1. One of the changes with the biggest problem is openSearch

Requirements:

- Composer 2.2
- Elasticsearch 7.17 or OpenSearch 1.2
- MariaDB  10.4 or MySQL 8.0
- PHP 8.1
- RabbitMQ 3.9
- Redis 6.2
- Varnish 7.0
- Apache 2.4 or nginx 1.18

For example, 2.4.3 is fully tested with MariaDB 10.4. Adobe recommends that you upgrade to MariaDB 10.4 before upgrading to 2.4.3.

**You setup a new Magento site use Upgrade compatibility Tool Magento:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74058876/how-install-upgrade-compatibility-tool-magento-and-phpstorm

Comment: You upgraded from 2.4 to 2.4.5?. Actually I have the extensions develop on the 2.4.4, so how much we have to work on the 2.4.5?

Comment: It doesn't really depend much on classes that are deprecated, but if you use the Phpstorn IDE you can verify that the classes still exist in 2.4.5

Comment: I just migrated Magento 2.3.4 to Magento 2.4.5. It didn't take me a long time to update. You may be having problems with OpenSearch.

Comment: I also upgrading from 2.4.3 P1 to 2.4.5 P1. I am working on my custom modules

Comment: On Changing the store view in Magento 2.4.5 P1 doesn't change the language

Comment: After changing the view you should do [ bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f ]
or specify the language example: setup:static-content:deploy en_US es_ES -f

Comment: It's working but by applying the language pack

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Magento 2.4.5 is now good to go in cases:

- You setup a new Magento site
- You upgrade from an older Magento version and your custom modules,
  3rd-party modules compatible with PHP 8.1

If case you upgrade from an older Magento version and your site has many custom modules, 3rd-party modules, you have to make your custom modules compatible with PHP 8.1, and make sure your 3rd-party modules are compatible with PHP 8.1 too.

It is worth noting that Magento 2.4.5-p1 was released some days ago - October 11, 2022, so you should install/upgrade to **2.4.5-p1** instead of 2.4.5.

Comment: Actually I have the extensions develop on the 2.4.4, so how much we have to work on the 2.4.5?

Comment: As 2.4.4 and 2.4.5 use the same PHP version (8.1), so it won't much work when you upgrade to 2.4.5. Don't forget to mark the answer you believe is the best solution to your question as accepted.

Comment: Sorry I have the 2.4.3 p1 with PHP 7.4 version

Comment: Does your site have many extensions/custom modules? For 3rd-party modules (extensions), you should check each module to know if it is compatible with Magento 2.4.5 - PHP 8.1 or not. For your custom modules, I think it doesn't take time to make them compatible with Magento 2.4.5 - PHP 8.1

Comment: Its about the custom modules not the third party extensions.

Comment: So, now you can upgrade your site locally and fix all issues to make your custom modules compatible with Magento 2.4.5 - PHP 8.1.

Comment: Yes, But the question is that we have to work more or little work

Comment: I'm actually saying ablout that above, that is a little work.

Comment: okay got it hope it will be.

Answer (score 0):

After working on the Magento 2.4.5 and Magento 2.4.5 P1 I can recommend everyone to go with this version is good to go.